# Node.js, chunked encoding, and persistent/reusable sockets

Tags: node.js, sockets, chunked

I'm building an application that talks to a vendor API. The API expects chunked encoding connections POST over https (and talks XML but that's irrelevant). They also recommend to multiplex requests over one socket connection (not doing so has security limitations as described below).

Node's core https works to the extent that I can establish *one* connection with the remote web service. I just set *'Transfer-Encoding': 'chunked'* header. The problems start when I make a second request to cancel the first request at the remote web service API.  The second request comes in on a separate connection and as such is not authorized to affect the conditions set in the first request – only requests that would be on the same socket would be authorized to do so.

What are my options to make this happen with Node.js? I've been looking at Mikeal Rogers' [request library](https://github.com/mikeal/request), but have [not been having luck with it](https://github.com/mikeal/request/issues/401) thus far.

Any ideas what route I could go?  Many thanks for any insights!

Comment: I'd essentially want to do with Node (as a client, connecting to a remote web service) what is discussed regarding Java here: [Java maintaining a persistent TCP connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9527515/java-maintaining-a-persistent-tcp-connection)

Comment: It may be a bad idea to attempt to make multiple, non-sequential requests over one socket connection ("[HTTP is a request-response protocol!](http://www.innovation.ch/java/HTTPClient/fullduplex.html)"), but unfortunately I didn't build the vendor web service API that doesn't allow mode changes to the original request (such as terminating it) unless it arrives over the same socket. I'm still searching for a solution. If it turns out Node is unable to handle this, I may need to write a proxy helper with Python's [Requests library](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/).